# CSV field delimiter problem

Tags: csv, delimiter

This CSV file has a field delimiter of `$`
 
 It looks like this:

```
14$"ALL0053"$$$"A"$$$"Direct Deposit in FOGSI A/c"$$"DR"$"DAS PRADIP ...
```

How can I view the file as columns, each field shown as in columns in a table.

I've tried many ways, none work. Any one knows how?

I am using **Ubuntu**

Comment: This isn't really CSV. I guess you could call it DSV (Dollar Seperated!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a weird CSV. Since a comma-separated file is usually separated by, well, commas. I think all you need to do is use a simple find/replace available in any text editor.

Open the file in [Gnome Edit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) and look under `Edit > Replace...`

From there you can specify to replace all `$`s with `,`s

Once your file is a real CSV, you can open it in [Open Office Calc](http://sc.openoffice.org/) (spreadsheet), or really any other spreadsheet program for Ubuntu (GNOME).

Answer (score 2):

```
cut -d $ -f 1,2,...x filename | sed 's/\$/ /g'
```

if you only want particular columns, and you don't want to see the $

or

```
sed 's/\$/ /g' filename
```

if you just want the $ to be replaced by a space

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything...you might as well invoke cat.

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu right-click on the file hit open with.. then OpenOffice Calc. then you should see a dialog box asking for delimiters etc. uncheck comma and and in the "other" field type a $. then hit okay and it will import it for you.

N

Answer (score 0):

As a first attempt:

```
column -ts'$' path
```

but this doesn't handle empty fields well, so fix that with this ugly hack:

```
sed 's/\$\$/$ $/g' path | column -ts$
```